# Is it possible to change buggy class in a closed source library that was not built to support dependency injection?

Tags: java, classloader

Say I am using a closed source java library with a known buggy class, say `BuggyClass` and this class is hardcoded throughout the rest of the library. So I would imagine that the java library looks something like this:

```
public class BuggyClass {
    public T buggyMethod (...) {
        // Buggy code here
    }
}
```

with several other classes in the library that make use of this class:

```
public class Example {
    private BuggyClass = new BuggyClass(); // No dependency injection possible

    public Example (/* No way to pass in my own subclass of BuggyClass*/) {
        //  ...
    }
}
```

etc...

Is there any hack, or workaround, possibly using the class loader so that I could subclass `BuggyClass` and get `Example` (and every other class in the library that has `BuggyClass` hardcoded in) to use my subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do a subclass, no, but you can write your own `BuggyClass` entirely and make sure it appears *earlier* in the classpath than the real one. I don't think it's [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.1), but the default classloader seems to typically use the first matching class it finds.

But obviously this is a Really Bad Option, so you want to exhaust every other avenue before trying to <s>solve</s> *temporarily work around* the underlying problem this way.

Example: Suppose we have this:

```
// The "buggy" class
package somepackage;

public class BuggyClass {
    public String someMethod() {
        return "I'm in the buggy class";
    }
}
```

and this:

```
// Uses the "buggy" class
package somepackage;

public class BuggyClassUser {
    public String useBuggyClass() {
        BuggyClass c = new BuggyClass();
        return c.someMethod();
    }
}
```

compiled and the classes in `buggy.jar`. Then we have this test class:

```
import somepackage.*;

public class Test {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        BuggyClassUser u = new BuggyClassUser();
        System.out.println(u.useBuggyClass());
    }
}
```

If we run that (*nix format classpath):

```
java -cp .:buggy.jar Test
```

...we see

```
I'm in the buggy class
```

But if we create a `somepackage` directory and put this in it:

```
package somepackage;

public class BuggyClass {
    public String someMethod() {
        return "I'm in the fixed class"; // <== Difference here
    }
}
```

...and compile that, since we have that in our classpath in front of the jar, this command:

```
java -cp .:buggy.jar Test
```

...**now** gives us this:

```
I'm in the fixed class
```

Again, this is very, very much a workaround, not a solution.